# how to aggregate elements of a list of tuples if the tuples have the same first element?

Tags: python, list, aggregate

I have a list in which each value is a list of tuples. for example this is the value which I extract for a key :

```
     [('1998-01-20',8) , ('1998-01-22',4) , ('1998-06-18',8 ) , ('1999-07-15' , 7), ('1999-07-21',1) ]
```

I have also sorted the list. 
now I want to aggregate the values like this :

```
    [('1998-01' , 12 ) , ('1998-06' ,8 ) , ('1999-07',8 )]
```

in some sense I want to group my tuples in terms of month , to sum the ints for each month together , I have read about groupby and I think it can't help me with my data structure because I have no idea what I'll be facing in my list so I'm trying to find a way to say : start from the first elements of the tuples if i[0][:6] are equal : sum i[1] . but I'm facing difficulty to implement this idea .

```
    for i in List :
        if i[0][:6] # *problem* I don't know how to say my condition :
        s=sum(i[1]) #?
```

I would appreciate any advices as I'm a new user of python!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another answer different from the ones given already. You can simpy create a new dictionary where the keys are the year-month combinations. A loop over the dates in your list + using `dictionary.get(key, defaultvalue)` should do the trick. IT adds the current value to the value in the new dictionary, if the key did not yet exist, it returns the default value 0 and creates the key.

```
data = [('1998-01-20',8) , ('1998-01-22',4) , ('1998-06-18',8 ) , ('1999-07-15' , 7), ('1999-07-21',1)]
dictionary = dict()
for (mydate, val) in data: #
    ym = mydate[0:7]    # the key is only the year month combination (i.e. '1998-01' for example)
    dictionary[ym] = dictionary.get(ym, 0) + val  # return the value for that key or return default 0 (and create key)

data_aggregated = [(key, val) for (key, val) in dictionary.iteritems()] # if you need it back in old format
```

Answer (score 18):

Try using `itertools.groupby` to aggregate values by month:

```
from itertools import groupby
a = [('1998-01-20', 8), ('1998-01-22', 4), ('1998-06-18', 8), 
     ('1999-07-15', 7), ('1999-07-21', 1)]

for key, group in groupby(a, key=lambda x: x[0][:7]):
    print key, sum(j for i, j in group)

# Output

1998-01 12
1998-06 8
1999-07 8
```

Here's a one-liner version:

```
print [(key, sum(j for i, j in group)) for key, group in groupby(a, key=lambda x: x[0][:7])]

# Output

[('1998-01', 12), ('1998-06', 8), ('1999-07', 8)]
```

Comment: thank you . It's a good solution but when I run it in my dataset I have results like :   2000-05 17
2000-05 17
2000-07 5
I'm trying to figure out why 2000-05 is repeated two times.

Comment: @Singu i dint get what your saying do your data have duplicates

Comment: no my data have no duplicates , I run it and I obtain the right results but I have no idea why for each query the first line of the results is printed two times! some more minutes and I'll give the feedback. thanks!

Comment: the groupby in itertools would work only when the input list is sorted based on the key. I wasted so much time on this.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict


DATA = [
    ('1998-01-20', 8),
    ('1998-01-22', 4),
    ('1998-06-18', 8),
    ('1999-07-15', 7),
    ('1999-07-21', 1),
]


groups = defaultdict(int)
for date, value in DATA:
    groups[date[:7]] += value


from pprint import pprint
pprint(groups)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you post the actual output.

Comment: this is a line from output : defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'2000-05': 17, '2000-07': 5})

Comment: Looks like it's working to me. That is just the `str` of a `defaultdict`. It's just like a normal `dict`. Look at `for key, value in groups.items(): print(key, value)`, you'll see it's working.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `defaultdict` for counting:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [('1998-01-20',8) , ('1998-01-22',4) , ('1998-06-18',8 ) , ('1999-07-15' , 7), ('1999-07-21',1)]

result = defaultdict(int)

for date, cnt in lst:
    year, month, day = date.split('-')
    result['-'.join([year, month])] += cnt

print(result)
```