# How to sum up a list of tuples having the same first element?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of tuples, for example:

```
    (1,3)
    (1,2)
    (1,7)
    (2,4)
    (2,10)
    (3,8)
```

I need to be able to sum up the second values based upon what the first value is, getting this result for the example list:

```
    (1,12)
    (2,14)
    (3,8)
```

This question is very similar in nature to [this one,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25740726/how-to-aggregate-elements-of-a-list-of-tuples-if-the-tuples-have-the-same-first) however, my solution may not use any imports or for loops, and all answers to that question use one or the other. It's supposed to rely on list and set comprehension.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: "It's supposed to rely on list and set comprehension." - bad task, then. Comprehensions can be useful, but they're the wrong tool for an operation like this. The natural comprehension-based solutions for this take quadratic time.

Comment: This is probably a homework problem for the "comprehensions" section of a python course.

Comment: Paul Rooney, my original thought was to use a map and key structure like I would use if programming in java and iterate through the list to sum to the correct key, but the restriction of using for loops significantly hampers my options. I also contemplated using Joran Beasley's answer, but was wondering if there was any way to do this that doesn't use quadratic time.

Comment: in which case it is a bad homework problem(or even worse interview problem...)... there are many places where comprehensions make lots of sense ... this is not a senario like that

Comment: @M.Paczek, in less restrictive languages where assignment was an expression rather than a statement, doing so would be possible (but ugly). However, that is not the case in python (to prevent mistakes like `if x = 1:pass`)

Comment: I hate these "code golf" questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_set = {x[0] for x in my_tuples}
my_sums = [(i,sum(x[1] for x in my_tuples if x[0] == i)) for i in my_set]
```

I guess. ... those requirements are not very good for this problem (this solution will be slow ...)

Comment: You could use a direct set comprehensoin (`{x[0]...}`) instead of a generator expression and the `set` builtin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python2, you can use map to behave like `izip_longest` and get the index of where the groups end:

```
def sums(l):
    st = set()
    inds = [st.add(a) or ind for ind, (a, b) in enumerate(l) if a not in st]
    return [(l[i][0], sum(sub[1] for sub in l[i:j])) for i, j in map(None, inds, inds[1:])]
```

Output:

```
In [10]: print(sums(l))
[(1, 12), (2, 14), (3, 8)]
```

for python 2 or 3 you can just use enumerate and check the index:

```
def sums(l):
    st = set()
    inds = [st.add(a) or ind for ind, (a, b) in enumerate(l) if a not in st]
    return [(l[j][0], sum(sub[1] for sub in (l[j:inds[i]] if i < len(inds) else l[inds[-1]:])))
            for i, j in enumerate(inds, 1)]
```

same output:

```
In [12]: print(sums(l))
[(1, 12), (2, 14), (3, 8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use dictionaries the following should work

```
x = [(1,3), (1, 2), (1, 7), (2, 4), (2, 10), (3, 8)]
d = {}
[d.__setitem__(first, d.get(first, 0) + second) for first, second in x]
print(list(d.items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward, but it's definitely O(n**2), so keep your input data small:

```
data = (
    (1,3),
    (1,2),
    (1,7),
    (2,4),
    (2,10),
    (3,8),
)

d = { k:v for k,v in data }
d2 = [(t1,sum( v for k,v in data if k == t1 )) for t1 in d.keys() ]
print(d2)
```

Output is

```
[(1, 12), (2, 14), (3, 8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict

x = [(1,3), (1, 2), (1, 7), (2, 4), (2, 10), (3, 8)]

d = defaultdict(int)

for k, v in x:
    d[k] += v

print(list(d.items()))
```

if you need a one-liner (lambda inline function) using itertools

```
from itertools import groupby

myfunc = lambda tu : [(k, sum(v2[1] for v2 in v)) for k, v in groupby(tu, lambda x: x[0])])

print(myfunc(x))
```