# Combine tuples in a list and get sum of second tuple element

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sum, tuples

I have a list of tuples:

```
tupples = [('d2', 1),
 ('d2', 1), ('d3', 1), ('d10', 1), ('d10', 1), ('d15', 1),
 ('d165', 1), ('d165', 1), ('d172', 1),('d2', 1)]
```

I want to combine like elements at 0, and sum all elements at 1 so the output looks like:

```
###[('d2',3),('d165',2),('d10',1),('d3',1),('d15',1),('d172',1)
```

```
new =[]
for item in tupples:
    if item[0] in item:
        sums = sum[item[1]]
    new.append((item[0],item1[1]))
```

Comment: `d = defaultdict(int); for k, v in tupples: d[k] += v`?

Comment: so the output will be `list_1` => all first items in tuple and `sum` which is the summation of all elements (2nd In tuple)??

Answer (score 1):

What about using [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) ?

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> list(pd.DataFrame(tupples).groupby(0).sum().to_dict()[1].items())
[('d10', 2), ('d15', 1), ('d165', 2), ('d172', 1), ('d2', 3), ('d3', 1)]
```

Comment: You will notice that my answer is different than those provided in [How to sum up a list of tuples having the same first element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35189438/how-to-sum-up-a-list-of-tuples-having-the-same-first-element). Any question @Ghostinshell ?