# Merging tuples together

Tags: python, mysql, sql

When I query my Mysql table to get results. I get a tuple back.

The tuple is like this:

```
(('Book 1', 1), ('Book 2', 1), ('Book 1', 2))
```

How do I get my tuple to be like this:

```
(('Book 1', 3), ('Book 2', 1))
```

Any suggestions in python or SQL would be helpful.

Comment: What is your code?  What is your SQL query? What have you tried?

Comment: I haven't got any code yet. I'm just looking for ideas to solve it.

Comment: Solve what? The problem isn't clear. Queries can return an arbitrary number of rows. They certainly don't return nested tuples. It's unclear what those numbers mean - why should `Book 1` have a 3 instead of 1, 2, 12, "1,2" ? Are you trying to count or sum stuff? Your actual SQL query is the most important information. What produces those books and values and what are those numbers supposed to be?

Comment: Check out: [How to sum up a list of tuples having the same first element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35189438/how-to-sum-up-a-list-of-tuples-having-the-same-first-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try SQL group by statement with aggregate function 'sum'
example

```
select book_name,sum(book_quantity) 
from your_table_name 
group by book_name
```